# Making an OpenGL GIS application

Tags: gdal, opengl

I am working on a project of mine in which I have to render geospatial data.  The data is in the form of geoTIFF images and I have to render that using OpenGL. I am good at C++ and OpenGL, but I don't have any knowledge about geospatial data.

I want to render the images in the form of texture but the GDAL library just makes the hillshade of the image and I don't know how to use the query in C++.

Comment: I think you will need to provide much more information, possibly a screen shot, of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, we need a lot more information before we could help, including an *exact* description of the data, the actual code which interacts with the data, and a more complete description of the error. You might find more hardcore C/C++ developers in [so] proper, but they'd need the same information.

Comment: Hi I want to do this too,Did you find out how could we do it?